# How do we define date format in HIVE create statment?

Tags: model, hive, hdfs

I am trying to create a HIVE table.My source date format is 'YYYY-MM-DD'.
Do I need to define the column as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD'?
or simply putting Date is enough?

Create table  
(
date_column date format 'YYYY-MM-DD')

In some of the source files, I have date fields in 'DD-MM-YYYY' format.
What will happen if I create a hive table column specifying only date 
example

Create table  
(
date_column date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Hive does not support `format` definition
2. Hive supports only the ISO date format `YYYY-MM-DD`
3. A value that cannot be rightly interpreted will be replaced by `NULL`

---

```
create table mytable (dt1 date,dt2 date);
insert into mytable values ('2017-05-18','18-05-2017');
select  * from mytable;
```

---

```
+------------+--------+
|    dt1     |  dt2   |
+------------+--------+
| 2017-05-18 | (null) |
+------------+--------+
```